# Update a single element in an array in MongoDB using NodeJS without knowing the index

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

In my database I have something that looks like this:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c0d9d54df58cb2fdc7f735a"),
"notificationMessages" : [ 
    {
        "message" : "Some message 1",
        "showNotification" : true,
        "projectId" : "5c0e40683500fe72a8e3ce8f"
    }, 
    {
        "message" : "Some message 2",
        "showNotification" : true,
        "projectId" : "5c0e6e113500fe72a8e3ce90"
    }
],
```

I want to update the "showNotification" to false when clicked on the concrete message on my client-side. To do this, I'm sending the index of what array I clicked on from the client-side to the nodejs server and I'm trying to use that result as the index for my update query, but it doesn't work. First I tried doing this:

```
  exports.delete_notification = async function(req,res) {

  let  arrayIndex = req.body.index;
console.log("This is the arrayIndex")
console.log(arrayIndex)


await User.update(
  {_id: req.session.userId},
  {$set: {'notificationMessages.' + arrayIndex + '.showNotification': false }}
)


res.status(200).json("done")
```

}

However, It seems as tho plusses are not allowed inside a update query:
[image]
(disregard the console.log(theString), theString doesn't exist I know, but that isn't the problem.)

So instead I tried doing this query

```
await User.update(
  {_id: req.session.userId},
  {$set: {'notificationMessages.arrayIndex.showNotification': false }}
)
```

This however results in following error:

```
(node:20656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: Cannot create field 'arrayIndex' in element {notificationMessages: [ { message: (....)
```

Anyone who can help me on how to properly update with a index that's recieved from the client-side?

Comment: See linked dupe. `{$set: {['notificationMessages.' + arrayIndex + '.showNotification']: false }}`

Comment: Thank you. Don't know how I didn't find that thread, but it solved my question

Answer (score 1):

Array Indexes are accessible by bracket notation.

```
await User.update(
  {_id: req.session.userId},
  {$set: { notificationMessages[arrayIndex].showNotification: false }}
)
```

Try doing it without the single quote. If it doesn't work you can alternatively try to template string it like the following:

```
await User.update(
  {_id: req.session.userId},
  {$set: { `notificationMessages[${arrayIndex}].showNotification`: false }}
)
```